# building new column with values depending on values above and below a specific row in r

Tags: r

Consider any data frame in long format (each row is one measurement point)

```
            col1   col2
row.name11    A     0      
row.name12    A     1      
row.name13    A     0     
row.name14    A     0    
row.name15    B     0      
row.name16    B     0     
row.name17    B     1
```

col1 indicates the participants (here just 2 individuals, A and B). col2 indicates with a 1 that at this measurement point an event has occurred (i.e., it indicates a status change for example from single to married).

Now, I would like to create a variable that is 0 for all measurement points prior to the event and 1 for the measurement point where the event occurs and is also 1 for all following measurement points.

```
             col1   col2  col3
row.name11    A     0     0 
row.name12    A     0     0
row.name13    A     1     1 
row.name14    A     0     1
row.name15    A     0     1
row.name16    B     0     0 
row.name17    B     0     0
row.name18    B     1     1
```

Do you have an advice how to do this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `cumsum` per group; here is a base R solution using `ave`

```
transform(df, col3 = ave(col2, col1, FUN = cumsum))
#           col1 col2 col3
#row.name11    A    0    0
#row.name12    A    1    1
#row.name13    A    0    1
#row.name14    A    0    1
#row.name15    B    0    0
#row.name16    B    0    0
#row.name17    B    1    1
```

Or the `dplyr` way

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(col2) %>% mutate(col3 = cumsum(col2))
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "            col1   col2
row.name11    A     0
row.name12    A     1
row.name13    A     0
row.name14    A     0
row.name15    B     0
row.name16    B     0
row.name17    B     1  ", header = T)
```

Comment: I've got another question that is related to this one. Would you mind helping me out on this one again? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51731930/create-time-axis-for-longitudinal-data-calculations-with-data-variables

Comment: @MarieB. You're very welcome. Always consider closing the question by setting the green check next to an answer. I have also posted an answer to your new question. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

`data.table` solution.

```
df[, cummax(col2), by = col1]
```

Where:

```
df <- data.frame(
  col1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), 
  col2 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)
)
```