# Create time axis for longitudinal data; calculations with data variables

Tags: r

I've got the following sample data frame. The data is in long format (longitudinal data). col1 indicates the person ID (for this sample we only have 2 people). col2 indicates the occurrence of a life event (e.g. 0 = not married, 1 = married). The status change from 0 to one actually marks the life event. col3 is 1 for each measurement occasion after the event and 0 for each measurement occasion prior to the event. The year indicates the year of assessment. The month indicates the month of assessment (02 = February).

```
             col1   col2  col3  year   month

row.name11    A     0     0     2013   02
row.name12    A     0     0     2014   02
row.name13    A     1     1     2015   02
row.name14    A     0     1     2016   02
row.name15    A     0     1     2018   02
row.name16    B     0     0     2014   02
row.name17    B     0     0     2015   02
row.name18    B     1     1     2016   02
row.name19    B     0     1     2017   04
```

I now wish to create an event-centered timeline. The new variable should be 0 when the event takes place (col2 == 1). It should be negative prior to the event (indicating the month until the event occurs) and positive after the event (indicating the month since the event has occurred).

It should look like this (see event.time variable):

```
             col1   col2  col3  year   month  event.time

row.name11    A     0     0     2013   02     -24
row.name12    A     0     0     2014   02     -12
row.name13    A     1     1     2015   02     0
row.name14    A     0     1     2016   02     12
row.name15    A     0     1     2018   02     36
row.name16    B     0     0     2014   02     -24
row.name17    B     0     0     2015   02     -12    
row.name18    B     1     1     2016   02     0
row.name19    B     0     1     2017   04     14
```

I figured out that I should transform my year and month variable into date-variables (using as.date function) first. However, I wasn't successful. How could I efficiently calculate the event.time variable afterwards? Maybe using the col3 because this variable indicates if it is prior or after the event?

I'm more than happy to receive any advices you may have! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#if nchar(month) is 1 then add 0 before month, otherwise use month directly. 
#1 added to make the transformation to as.Date simple
df$date<- paste0(df$year,'-',ifelse(nchar(df$month)==1,paste0(0,df$month),df$month),'-1')
df$date<- as.Date(df$date)

library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(col1) %>% 
       #Get the minmume date where col2==1 incase there is more than one 1 in the same ID
       mutate(date_used=min(date[col2==1]), event.time=as.numeric(date - date_used))


# A tibble: 9 x 8
# Groups:   col1 [2]
col1   col2  col3  year month date       date_used  event.time
<fct> <int> <int> <int> <int> <date>     <date>          <dbl>
1 A         0     0  2013     2 2013-02-01 2015-02-01       -730
2 A         0     0  2014     2 2014-02-01 2015-02-01       -365
3 A         1     1  2015     2 2015-02-01 2015-02-01          0
4 A         0     1  2016     2 2016-02-01 2015-02-01        365
5 A         0     1  2018     2 2018-02-01 2015-02-01       1096
6 B         0     0  2014     2 2014-02-01 2016-02-01       -730
7 B         0     0  2015     2 2015-02-01 2016-02-01       -365
8 B         1     1  2016     2 2016-02-01 2016-02-01          0
9 B         0     1  2017     4 2017-04-01 2016-02-01        425
```

## Data

```
df <- read.table(text="
         col1   col2  col3  year   month
         row.name11    A     0     0     2013   02
         row.name12    A     0     0     2014   02
         row.name13    A     1     1     2015   02
         row.name14    A     0     1     2016   02
         row.name15    A     0     1     2018   02
         row.name16    B     0     0     2014   02
         row.name17    B     0     0     2015   02
         row.name18    B     1     1     2016   02
         row.name19    B     0     1     2017   04
                 ",header=T)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your code using the sample data. Unfortunately, I get a "2015-02-01" for all rows in the date_used column instead of getting the date-value for col2==1 (separately for each group of participants). Do have any idea what could have went wrong? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Probably `group_by` did not work as intended due to name collision between `dplyr` and `plyr`. Try loading dplyr only on a fresh R session. Or call `group_by` explicitly as `dplyr::group_by`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `lubridate`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
ym <- function(y, m) ymd(sprintf("%s-%s-01", y, m))
df %>%
    group_by(col1) %>%
    mutate(event.time = interval(ym(year, month)[col2 == 1], ym(year, month)) %/% months(1))
## A tibble: 9 x 6
## Groups:   col1 [2]
#  col1   col2  col3  year month event.time
#  <fct> <int> <int> <int> <int>      <dbl>
#1 A         0     0  2013     2       -24.
#2 A         0     0  2014     2       -12.
#3 A         1     1  2015     2         0.
#4 A         0     1  2016     2        12.
#5 A         0     1  2018     2        36.
#6 B         0     0  2014     2       -24.
#7 B         0     0  2015     2       -12.
#8 B         1     1  2016     2         0.
#9 B         0     1  2017     4        14.
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "             col1   col2  col3  year   month
row.name11    A     0     0     2013   02
row.name12    A     0     0     2014   02
row.name13    A     1     1     2015   02
row.name14    A     0     1     2016   02
row.name15    A     0     1     2018   02
row.name16    B     0     0     2014   02
row.name17    B     0     0     2015   02
row.name18    B     1     1     2016   02
row.name19    B     0     1     2017   04", header = T)
```

Comment: Hi Maurits Evers, I tried your code this morning and it worked fine (with my own data and this sample data). However, if I try to reproduce it now I get the following warning message: Note: method with signature ‘Timespan#Timespan’ chosen for function ‘%/%’,
 target signature ‘Interval#Period’.
 "Interval#ANY", "ANY#Period" would also be valid
Warning messages:
1: In as.numeric(end) - as.numeric(start) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In unclass(e1) + unclass(e2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length. Any ideas why?

Comment: @MarieB. Hmm. Sounds strange. The note can be safely ignored. I can't reproduce the warning. Can you run this again from a fresh R terminal?

Comment: I did, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work reliably. The event.time variable is not exact even though I reproduced the same code with the exact same sample data in a fresh R session. This comment option does not allow to post the tibble I've got now. But its c(-24, -24, 0, 0, 36, -24, 0, 0, 26) for the above sample data. What irritates me the most is that it actually worked yesterday but does not work any more. Usually it's an user problem and not something R does differently now, but I have no idea what I did wrong.

Comment: @MarieB. That seems very strange. Make sure you don't have any other packages loaded. If you copy&paste my code above into a fresh R terminal (make sure you don't restore a saved workspace), the code above must work. Can you confirm that?